# Clicking button in User Control 1 makes API call in aspx.cs class, but fails to populate data in User Control 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, eventhandler, asp-usercontrols

Clicking the "Go" button in my first User Control does everything I want except my second User Control fails to populate the data into the ListView asp control after it receives and binds data to the User Control.

Odd behavior it also does is cycle (iterate) multiple times through the public EventHandler method I created for it.  It's totally weird.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by wrapping a "asp:UpdatePanel" within one of the controls I was using.  The User Control that actually contained the "GO" button_click event.

The solution was to take out the UpdatePanel ASP control and to put it in the aspx (html) page instead and to put the two User Controls I was using inside of the update panel (to make it appear like there is no post-back occurring!  Thank you Sathish!  :D

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/163038/Approaches-for-User-Control-Event-Handling